# Helm-projectile doesn't ignore files

Tags: projectile, helm-projectile

I'm using helm with projectile and trying to exclude various files from the output that are project specific (i.e with `.projectile` files, not `globally` variable). The problem is that it never works for me, e.g in my `.emacs.d` folder i have a `.cask` folder, so i'm adding the following line to the `.projectile` file:

```
-/.cask
```

This invalidates my projectile cache and everything is clean, but if i open any file under `.cask` directory, it's added to the cache and i can see the file in `helm-projectile` output. Maybe i understand the guide incorrectly, but adding `-/.cask` to the `.projectile` file i expect it to ignore any file under this project root path.

Comment: It sounds like you did invalidate your cache, but did you actually try deleting your projectile cache file? I have had mixed results with ignoring files (sometimes it works for me and sometimes it doesn't), but simply calling `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` from the project never seems to work for me to clear out the cache. Usually deleting the `projectile.cache` file and letting it rebuild itself works better than nothing for me...Hope you get a better solution though, because I have always gotten inconsistent results (probably I am missing something)

Comment: @elethan i'm not doing anything with the cache file, actually when i'm editting something in .projectile file and restart emacs, invalidation runs on its own, i'm not calling it manually. And yes, the cache is empty, but when i open some file which is under the folder that should be ignored i can see the message that this file is added to the cache and then i can see it among other files in helm-projectile. Worth to mention, that adding the folder to the globally ignored folders list works just fines and in this case i don't see the file